# Android: preference activity. Dependency by list values

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

How to set dependency by the ListPreference values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already pointed out by Snicolas, the depency xml feature only checks for a boolean state (= if the referenced key is true or a value is set in it). If enabled, you can use this preference, if it is not, you can't.

To archieve a depency when a certain ListPreference entry is selected, you have to write some logic in code. I'd solve this by using a `OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener`. When the preference/key thats associated with your ListPreference changes, test to which value it has changed. If it now has one that enables or disables your preference, use `Preference.setEnabled()` to change it.

Comment: If you want to see some code for this approach, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969807/listpreference-dependency

Answer (score 1):

Dependency means that "If the other Preference is not set or is off, this Preference will be disabled."

It's got nothing to do with values.

REgards,
 stéphane