# How to make EditTextPreference depending on ListPreference?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a ListPreference with to items.

Now I would like to activate the EditTextPreference only if item2 is selected and deactivated if item1 is selected.

android:dependency=" " does not work

How can I do that?

I found this but I don't understand it: [ListPreference dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969807/listpreference-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the dependency of the list item

```
itemList = (ListPreference)findPreference("itemList");
itemList2 = (ListPreference)findPreference("itemList2");
itemList.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    final String val = newValue.toString();
    int index = itemList.findIndexOfValue(val);
    if(index==3)
      itemList2.setEnabled(true);
    else
      itemList2.setEnabled(false);
    return true;
  }
});
```

you can change it according to your requirement

Comment: I linked to that answer...

findPreferance is deprecated and I don't know how to adapt the code to my wishes. Can you help me?